# What makes printk() write to the console even if it begins with KERN_INFO?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

As I understand the system control variable, the first value in `kernel.printk` is the number that kernel messages must be smaller than in order to be written to the console. So, if it is `4`, then message produced by this will only be visible with `dmesg`:

```
printk(KERN_INFO "This is a kernel message.");
```

The only time a message will appear on the console is if it was preceded by `KERN_ERR`, `KERN_CRIT`, `KERN_INFO`, or `KERN_EMERG`. Even if something went wrong with a kernel module, I would expect that messages like the above would not appear on my screen.

One of the things I am trying my hand at is system call interception. Some have worked flawlessly and others have not. But on several occasions, messages from my unsuccessful kernel modules marked with `KERN_INFO` have clogged my console, not giving me enough time between messages to unload them. The screw up is occurring somewhere in these lines of code:

```
…
#define INODE_IS_DEVICE(inode) (S_ISBLK(inode->i_mode) || S_ISCHR(inode->i_mode))
#define INODE_IS_RAW(inode) (imajor(inode) == RAW_MAJOR)
#define INODE_IS_RAW_DEVICE(inode) (INODE_IS_DEVICE(inode) || INODE_IS_RAW(inode))
#define TEST_OPEN_FLAGS(flags) ((flags & O_WRONLY) || (flags & O_RDWR))
…
struct inode *current_inode;
…
struct inode* get_inode_from_pathname(const char pathname) {
    struct path path;
    kern_path(pathname, LOOKUP_FOLLOW, &path);
    return path.dentry->d_inode;
}

asmlinkage int (*real_open)(const char* __user, int, int);

asmlinkage int custom_open(const char* __user file_name, int flags, int mode) {
    current_inode = get_inode_from_pathname(file_name);
    printk(KERN_INFO "intercepted: open(\"%s\", %X, %X)\n", file_name, flags, mode);
    if (INODE_IS_RAW_DEVICE(inode) && TEST_OPEN_FLAGS(flags)) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Intercepted call to write to block device %s.\n", file_name);
    }
    return real_open(file_name, flags, mode);
}
…
void hack(void) {
    make_rw((unsigned_long)sys_call_table);
    real_open = (void*)*(sys_call_table + __NR_open);
    *(sys_call_table + __NR_open) = (unsigned_long)custom_open;
    make_ro((unsigned_long)sys_call_table);
}

void restore(void) {
    make_rw((unsigned_long)sys_call_table);
    *(sys_call_table + __NR_open) = (unsigned_long)real_open;
    make_ro((unsigned_long)sys_call_table);
}
```

The code for `make_rw` and `make_ro` are identical to the ones found [here](http://syprog.blogspot.com/2011/10/hijack-linux-system-calls-part-iii.html). Compiling this code gave me no errors, but loading the modules results in the messages being orinted to the console as well as some kind crash or error. Note, that when the block of code inside `custom_open` is replaced with

```
    printk(KERN_INFO "intercepted: open(\"%s\", %X, %X)\n", file_name, flags, mode);
    if (file_name == "/dev/sda" && TEST_OPEN_FLAGS(flags)) {
        printk("Intercepted call to write to block device.");
        return -EPERM;
    }
    return real_open(file_name, flags, mode);
```

everything works the way I want it to. Replacing `custom_open`'s control flow statement instead with `print(KERN_INFO "i_mode of %s: %hu\n", file_name, current_inode->i_mode);` produces the exact same problem.

I'm not sure what's producing the error here. Any insights?

Comment: What does `cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk` say?

Answer (score 0):

The kernel variable DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LOGLEVEL decides what is the default log level of your kernel. To know what is the current value of it, check the value of CONFIG_DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LOGLEVEL in your kernel's config file.

This will give you clue as to why the KERN_INFO is coming to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

> Note, that when the block of code inside `custom_open` is replaced
>   with
>
> ```
>     printk(KERN_INFO "intercepted: open(\"%s\", %X, %X)\n", file_name, flags, mode);
>     if (file_name == "/dev/sda" && TEST_OPEN_FLAGS(flags)) {
>         printk("Intercepted call to write to block device.");
>         return -EPERM;
>     }
>     return real_open(file_name, flags, mode);
> ```
>
> everything works the way I want it to.

You are mistaken. That you see no output from the above code does not mean that `printk` does not output to the console; it is rather likely that the `printk` is never executed, because the function parameter `file_name` most probably doesn't point to the memory location of the string literal `"/dev/sda"` - remember, to compare strings, `strcmp` is to be used.

Comment: The output of `dmesg` says otherwise. It shows up in the kernel log buffer, it just doesn't get printed to the console/terminal in that case.